# VS Code Decorator Extension Above/Below specified Range

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there currently any way I can create an extension that applies a text decorator above or below the specified range which I can use to supply any HTML/CSS visual I want?

I'm still working through the API and my guess is either no, or not directly via the extensions API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what types of decorations you are talking about. Since you used the words "text decorator" then I'm going to assume you're talking about the decoration API described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-namedecorationrenderoptionsaspan-classcodeitem-id262decorationrenderoptionsspan).

As you can see, there are several css properties that they officially support, but none of them "arbitrary css".

What I've done, though, in my [vscode dimmer extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-dimmer), is apply an opacity style using this technique:

```
dimDecoration = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType(<vscode.DecorationRenderOptions> {
    textDecoration: `none; opacity: ${opacity / 100}`
});
```

When vscode sees this, it basically adds `text-decoration: none; opacity: 1` to the stylesheet.This allows me to use arbitrary styling.

The above snippet creates a "Decoration" which can then be applied to ranges as shown below.

```
function dimEditor(editor: vscode.TextEditor) {
    if (!dimDecoration) return;

    let startPosition = new vscode.Position(0, 0)
    let endPosition = new vscode.Position(editor.document.lineCount, Number.MAX_VALUE);
    editor.setDecorations(dimDecoration, [new vscode.Range(startPosition, endPosition)]);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** Of course, this isn't officially supported and they could change the way they process the arguments to stop at the first `;` and anybody using this workaround would have a broken extension.

**Edit:**

If you're wanting to have a "hover" behavior, there is the [HoverProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#HoverProvider) api. It can take a "marked string" which is essentially markdown, and display it. This [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview) uses it to display img previews on hover.

[image]

If markdown will meet your needs you can try that, otherwise you can try with arbitrary HTML and see if it accepts that.

Comment: That's a cool extension, what I need is to display a small box below the cursors current position, in a similar fashion to IntelliSense
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense
but it doesn't seem possible to do that via the current API's

Comment: please update your question description to include these extra details. The words you used (text decorator) refer to a very different concept in the vs code api :-)

Comment: I've seen the HoverProvider API's, unfortunately I need more control over when the decorator appears, hovering doesn't cut it... though it might if I change my design... I'll think about it